# Limit of continuously differentiable, Lebesgue integrable function whose derivative is also Lebesgue integrable

Tags: solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f\colon [0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable and both $f$ and $f'$ are Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$. Then, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

I guess, I need the fundamental theorem of calculus, i.e.,
$$
F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\, dt,
$$
where
$F'(x)=f(x)$.

Then, I think I may use

$$f(x)=F'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)\, dt=\int_0^x f'(t)\, dt$$

We have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x f'(t)\, dt=\int_0^\infty f'(t)\, dt=c\in\mathbb{R}$ since $f'$ is Lebesgue-integrable, i.e. $\int_0^\infty\lvert f'(t)\rvert\, dt<\infty$. Thus, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$. But since $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,\infty)$, meaning $\int_{0}^\infty\lvert f(x)\rvert\, dx <\infty$, we need to have $c=0$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write for all $x \ge 0$:
$$
f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t) dt \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^\infty f'(t)dt = c < \infty
$$

Since the limit exists (normally you could only assume $\liminf_{x\rightarrow \infty} |f| = 0$ if $f \in L^1[0, \infty)$).

If $|c| > 0$ then eventually $|f(x)| \ge |c| / 2 > 0$, for $x$ big enough.
$$
\infty > \int_{0}^{\infty} |f| \ge \int_{|f| \ge |c| /2}^{\infty} |f| > \infty
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, seems not to be very different from my idea.

Comment: Yes it is, I would have posted it in a comment but was not allowed as a new user.

Comment: By the way: Why can I use Riemann integrals here, that is, how can I deduce that $f$ and $f$ are also Riemann integrable?

Comment: The functions are continuous, they are bounded on every compact and therefore the  Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide on compacts. $\int_0^n f d\lambda = \int_0^n f(t) dt$. Taking the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$, the left side goes to $\int_0^{\infty} f d\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore the improper Riemann integral is finite and they coincide.